# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have been trying to import all my scss files in single styles.scss file and import that in my components to avoid too many style imports. But I am getting above error for variables. The variable has been declared globally in 'src/assets/styles/variables.scss' and the variable.scss file has been imported in main style.scss and that has been imported in component's scss file. I am using 'sass' package as 'node-sass' is deprecated (as per my google research). Also not using any css framework such as bootstrap.

My file structure:

styles.scss

```css
@import url('./variables.scss');
@import url('./layout.scss');
@import url('./mixin.scss');
```

component.scss

```css
@import url('./styles.scss');

.card {
     background: $mint;
}
```

variables.scss

```css
$mint : #B1F8E7;
```

I have tried and checked many answers on similar posts but didn't work. Other normal css from other files ex: layout.scss from styles.scss gets applied to the component. It's the variables and mixins that are not working.

Checked this : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/ Does this mean I have to include variables and mixins in each component? can't I have single styles.scss and import that instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out by using @forward and @use. So for mixins, variables and functions we need to write @forward in the main style.scss and then this file, can be included in component.scss using @use.

So global styles.scss now looks like:

```css
@forward "./variables.scss";
@forward "./mixin.scss";
@use "./form-controls.module.scss";
@use "./layout.module.scss";
```

and component.scss looks like

```css
@use "./assets/styles/styles.scss" as *;

.responsive {
  background-color: $mint;
  @include breakpoints(medium, large) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  @include breakpoints(small) {
    background-color: $mint;
  }
  
}
```

This works absolutely fine. But can someone tell me if this is ideal?